# Even when the GPS signal is lost, the GPS location information is still there

Tags: android, gps, location

```
  Location gpsLocation = appLocationService.getLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
  if ( gpsLocation != null) {  
       //Why gps location information is still available ?  
  }
```

Comment: It's in the name: "getLastKnownLocation".

Comment: You might try checking the timestamp in the returned `Location`. If that is older than X, assume it is invalid. However, I'm not sure that this works on all devices, you might get a recent timestamp even if the data is old. Try it!

Answer (score 0):

If you find that GPS location information is still available even when the GPS signal is lost, it's important to understand that `getLastKnownLocation` retrieves the most recently known location based on the last GPS fix. This means that if your device had a valid GPS fix and you called `getLastKnownLocation` before the GPS signal was lost, you would receive the last known location.

To address this issue and ensure that you are getting up-to-date location information, you should use location updates instead of relying solely on the last known location. The Android Location API provides a way to receive real-time location updates, which can be used to track the device's location as it changes.

Here is an example of how you can request location updates using the Location API:

```java
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // Handle the updated location data here
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // Handle changes in the location provider status (e.g., GPS signal lost)
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // Handle when the location provider is enabled
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // Handle when the location provider is disabled
    }
};

// Request location updates from the GPS provider
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
```

With this approach, you register a `LocationListener` to receive location updates, and you can react to changes in the location data as well as the status of the GPS provider.

Keep in mind that the `onLocationChanged` method will be called as new location updates become available, allowing you to continuously track the device's location. If the GPS signal is lost or regained, the `onStatusChanged` method will provide information about the status of the provider.

Remember to request location updates and handle location data and provider status in your app as needed, ensuring that you adapt to changes in the GPS signal.